# How to edit nested collections in MVC5?

Tags: entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a EF-model which contains a "key" and a "value". The value-table contains a FK to the key. In the EF-model it looks like this:

```
public partial class dict_key
{
    public dict_key()
    {
        this.dict_value = new HashSet<dict_value>();
    }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<dict_value> dict_value { get; set; } //dict_value contains a string "value"
}
```

My controller is passing the information for editing like this:

```
// GET: Keys/Texts/5
[Authorize]
public async Task<ActionResult> Texts(int? id)
{
    var key = await db.dict_key
        .Include(x => x.dict_value)
        .Where(x => x.id.Equals(id.Value))
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    return View(key);
    // Debugging 'key' shows that dict_value has 3 correct values.
}
```

This gets passed to my View which shows the dict_value's correct:

```
@model Dict.Models.dict_key
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>Key: @Model.name </div>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Language</th>
            <th>Text</th>
        </tr>
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.dict_value.Count(); i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td> @Model.dict_value.ElementAt(i).dict_lang.name_en </td>
                <td> @Html.EditorFor(x => x.dict_value.ElementAt(i).value) </td>
            </tr>
        }
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </div>
    </table>
}
```

When submitting my changes back to the controller...

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Texts(dict_key dict_key)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Also tried: db.Entry(dict_key).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.Entry(dict_key.dict_value).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Texts");
    }
    return View(dict_key);
}
```

..then my "dict_key" is totally different from the object I passed to my edit-view. The passed object contained the collection of dict_value's and the "returned" and edited object returns with the proper key object, but with an empty dict_value collection.

I try to avoid using a userdefined model or the viewbag to do all of that stuff manually. What is the best practise solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

`Collection.ElementAt` doesn't generate a proper field name in Razor. You need a `List`. Here you should use a view model instead of your entity directly and simply make your `dict_value` collection a `List<dict_value>` there.

Alternatively, you can create an editor template for `dict_value` and then in your view just do:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.dict_value)
```

Where `dict_value` there is your entire collection. Razor will render an instance of the editor template for each member of the collection and properly index everything.